# com.amazonaws.services.gluejobexecutor.model.InternalServiceException: Item size to update has exceeded the maximum allowed size

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, amazon-s3, pyspark, aws-glue

I'm using AWS Glue as an ETL Job to transform data from S3 and writing to another S3 bucket using bookmarking.

I am receiving this unexpected exception on a scheduled Job which was running without any problematic until the previous day:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "my_script.py", line 123, in <module>
job.commit()

[...]

py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:com.amazonaws.services.glue.util.Job.commit.
: com.amazonaws.services.gluejobexecutor.model.InternalServiceException: Item size to update has exceeded the maximum allowed size 
(Service: AmazonDynamoDBv2; Status Code: 400; Error Code: ValidationException; Request ID: /) 
(Service: AWSGlueJobExecutor; Status Code: 500; Error Code: InternalServiceException; Request ID: /)
```

I see in the error message is mentioned Dynamo DB but I'm not using at all this service (so I suspect it is internally used in Glue).

What is causing this exception?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I **Reset job bookmark** from the Glue Console and the problem was solved, succeeding the Job execution